# Applying a function to a list of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a set of data in a dataframe (df), generated from another programme, which outputs to csv. It looks something like this:

```
   | |Molecule |Conversion factor |Condition1 |Condition2 |Condition3 |...|
|0  |A        |-0.5              |-5.5       |-5.7       |-5.9||
|1  |B        |-0.1              |-10.3      |-10.6      |-11.0||
|2  |C        |-0.3              |-6.5       |-6.6       |-6.7||
```

Because the conditions are the result of another calculation, the condition header names are variable, so I have generated a list of headers from the data called "condition_list".

I want to apply a function which does: conversion factor / condition, for every value in the columns listed in condition_list, but not the other columns (they are strings, so this gives errors).

The code I have so far is this:

```
condition_list = list(df.columns)
del condition_list[:2]

def conversion(x):
    return [1] * x ** -1

df = apply(lambda x: conversion(x) if x.name in [condition_list] else x, axis=1)

print(df)
```

But it doesn't seem to read the list correctly, and so I get the original table back.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- it's a simple case of using your filter condition in comprehensions
- your conversion function is so simple (divide) I have elected to use a **lambda** function
- given your source data has structural issue it demonstrates that other columns are not included in calculation

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   | |Molecule |Conversion factor |Condition1 |Condition2 |Condition3 |...|
|0  |A        |-0.5              |-5.5       |-5.7       |-5.9||
|1  |B        |-0.1              |-10.3      |-10.6      |-11.0||
|2  |C        |-0.3              |-6.5       |-6.6       |-6.7||"""),sep="|",)

df.join(
    df.loc[:, ["Conversion factor "] + [c for c in df.columns if "Condition" in c]].apply(
        lambda s: pd.Series({f"{n}res": s["Conversion factor "] / s[n]
                             for n in s.index if n != "Conversion factor "}),
        axis=1,)
)
```

#### output

|  |  |  | Molecule | Conversion factor | Condition1 | Condition2 | Condition3 | ... | Unnamed: 8 | Condition1 res | Condition2 res | Condition3 res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 0 | A | -0.5 | -5.5 | -5.7 | -5.9 | nan | nan | 0.0909091 | 0.0877193 | 0.0847458 |
| 1 | nan | 1 | B | -0.1 | -10.3 | -10.6 | -11 | nan | nan | 0.00970874 | 0.00943396 | 0.00909091 |
| 2 | nan | 2 | C | -0.3 | -6.5 | -6.6 | -6.7 | nan | nan | 0.0461538 | 0.0454545 | 0.0447761 |